# SSH to a private VM with key authentication

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

I am new to Linux and this is my first time connecting to a private VM.
I was given a private address(no public since the file not does not have ".pud")

I am not sure how to use the given private key located on my desktop.

I think public and private keys were already configured on the server side. The user of the server only gave me the private key to access their server and I'm not sure how to use the private key I tried using `ssh -i (location public file) user@x.x.x.x` but then it says `Permission denied (publickey)`.

I am using UBUNTU 21.04

Comment: Please verify if the below works or not. And if not, please post `ssh -vvv ...` verbose output.

Answer (score 2):

You're close. The public key lives on the server. The private key is yours to keep secret. When you make a connection you should use the private key:

```
ssh -i (location PRIVATE file) user@x.x.x.x
```

`ssh` - OpenSSH SSH client [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh) states:

> `-i identity_file`
> Selects a file from which the identity (**private key**) for RSA or DSA authentication is read. The default is <strike>`~/.ssh/identity` for protocol version 1, and</strike> `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `~/.ssh/id_dsa` for protocol version 2. Identity files may also be specified on a per-host basis in the configuration file. It is possible to have multiple `-i` options (and multiple identities specified in configuration files).

Note: SSH protocol version 1 has already been deprecated, and therefore striked-through.

Answer (score -1):

With SSH, you have a public key (typically `id_rsa.pub`) and a private key (typically `id_rsa`). `ssh-keygen` should have generated both. You can add the `id_rsa.pub` content to the `.ssh/authorized_keys` of your server. This makes you able to log from your client with the private key.

You can have multiple keys on your server, they simply should be concatenated in the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file. (Typically copy the public key to the server and type `cat file.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys`.)

The `authorized_keys` is a text file, you can edit with your favorite editor.

Comment: I think public and private keys were already configured on the server side. The user of the server only game me the private key to access their server and Im not sure how to use the private key
I tried using ssh -i (location public file) user@x.x.x.x
then it says "Permission denied (publickey)"